# Problem with the definition of Work of a Force Field

Tags: analysis, curves

Given a force field $F:A\subseteq\mathbb{R^3}\to\mathbb{R^3}$ where A is an open connected set
and Given a regular curve $\phi:[a,b]\subseteq\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R^3}$ such that $\phi\left(\left[a,b\right]\right)\subseteq A$
my book defines the Work $W$ of $F$ to move a particle from $\phi(a)$ to $\phi(b)$ as:
$$W=\int_\phi\langle F,T\rangle dS$$
Where $\langle F(x),T(x)\rangle$ is the scalar product between $F(x)$ and the tangent versor $T(x)$ to the curve at the point $x\in\phi([a,b])$.
My problem with this definition is that we defined the tangent versor $T(t)$ to the curve at a point $t\in[a,b]$ as $T(t)=\frac{\phi^{'}(t)}{\Vert\phi^{'}(t)\Vert}$
so $T$ is a function that goes from $[a,b]\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R^3}$

while to consider the line integral $$\int_\phi f dS$$ i should have that $f$ is a function defined in $\phi\left(\left[a,b\right]\right)\subseteq\mathbb{R^3}$ to $\mathbb{R}$

but if the curve is not injective i can't consider the function $\langle F,T\rangle:\phi\left(\left[a,b\right]\right)\subseteq\mathbb{R^3}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

So i don't get if $\int_\phi\langle F,T\rangle dS$ is an abuse of notation to mean $\int_a^b\langle F(\phi(t)),T(t)\rangle\Vert\phi(t)\Vert dt$

Or if i need to suppose that $\phi$ is injective (or something similar like that $\phi$ is simple)

EDIT: the problem is that if $\phi$ is not injective i could have that for two different points $t_0$ and $t_1$ in [a,b] i have that $\phi(t_0)=\phi(t_1)$ and if $T(t_0)\neq T(t_1)$ i can't consider a function that for every $x\in \phi ([a,b])$ gives me the tangent versor to the curve $\phi$ at the point $x$. (because for the point $\phi(t_0)=\phi(t_1)$ i have two possible tangent versors to consider)

Answer (score 1):

Your assertion

> while to consider the line integral $$\int_\phi f dS$$ I should have
> that $f$ is a function defined in
> $\phi\left(\left[a,b\right]\right)\subseteq\mathbb{R^3}$ to
> $\mathbb{R^3}$

Is not correct. A line integral

$$\int_\phi f dS$$ is perfectly defined for $f : \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R$ by
$$\int_a^b f(\phi(t)) \Vert \phi^\prime(t) \Vert dt.$$

Comment: So? The problem is that $\langle F,T\rangle$ is not a definable function unless $\phi$ is injective

Comment: Why do you say that? For any $t \in [a,b]$, $F(\phi(t))$ is well defined as well as $T(t)$. If you have $\phi(t_1) = \phi(t_2)$ ($\phi$ not injective), then $F(\phi(t_1)) = F(\phi(t_2))$ while $T(t_1)$ may be different to $T(t_2)$.

Comment: Exactly so i can't consider a function $L:x\in\phi\left(\left[a,b\right]\right)\subseteq\mathbb{R^3}\to L(x)\in\mathbb{R^3}$ that gives me the tangent versor $L(x)$ for each $x \in  \phi\left(\left[a,b\right]\right)$ and so i can't consider $\int_\phi\langle F,L\rangle dS$ because i can't define $L$    (remember that i need that $\langle F,L\rangle$ is a function from $\mathbb{R^3}$ to $\mathbb{R^3}$  but i can't define $L$ from $\mathbb{R^3}$ to $\mathbb{R^3}$ do you get the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what you mean. You now speak of $L$ which is not defined in your question.

Comment: Do you agree that to define $\int_\phi f dS$ i need that f goes from $\mathbb{R^3}$ to $\mathbb{R^3}$ right? So to define $\int_\phi\langle F,T\rangle dS$ i would need that $\langle F,T\rangle$ goes from $\mathbb{R^3}$ to $\mathbb{R^3}$ but it's not the case since $T$ goes from [a,b] to  $\mathbb{R^3}$ and $F$ goes from $\mathbb{R^3}$ to $\mathbb{R^3}$

Comment: if $\phi$ is injective i can consider $L(x)=T(\phi^{-1}(x))$  which works as $T$ and it let me define $\int_\phi\langle F,L\rangle dS$ i can do that because $\langle F,T\rangle$ goes from $\mathbb{R^3}$ to $\mathbb{R^3}$.  But  if $\phi$ is not injective i can't do that

Comment: *Do you agree that to define $\int_\phi f dS i need that $f$ goes from $\mathbb R^3$ to $\mathbb R^3$ right?* **No**... this is what I wrote in my answer by the way.

Comment: I corrected it. But the problem it's not that

Comment: the problem is that $\langle F,T\rangle$ is not a function that goes from $\mathbb R^3$ to $\mathbb R$ . Because it's not even a function. In fact: $F$ goes from $\mathbb R^3$ to $\mathbb R^3$ BUT $T$ goes from [a,b] to $\mathbb R^3$ .

Comment: I’ll stop the discussion which is going in useless circles. **For sure $\langle F, T\rangle$ is a real map. It is the inner product!!!**

Comment: No problem. I discussed the topic with my analysis professor and he said that i am right. It is an abuse of notation. So you don't have to answer. Thanks anyway.